# How to prove the matrix identities $HXH = Z$ and $HZH = X$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, pauli-gates

As we know Hadamard gates are used to bring quantum bits into superposition states.

I’m trying to understand how  identities $HXH = Z$ & $HZH = X$ w.r.t rotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the matrix representations of these operations and with little algebra, things will become obvious.

$$H = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$X = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$Z = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then it is clear that
$$
HXH = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} =  Z$$

Things will follow similarly for $HZH$.

You can think of this operation as [change of basis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2LTAUO1TdA) in linear algebra. (Keep in mind that $H=H^{-1}=H^{†}$)

Answer (score 2):

$X$ is a 180$^{\circ}$ rotation about the x-axis,

$Z$ is a 180$^{\circ}$ rotation about the z-axis,

Since
$H$ swaps the x-axis with the z-axis, (and a subsequent $H$ swaps them back to their original orientation)

then: $HXH = Z$

Also because $H=H^{-1}$
and so:

$X = H^{-1}ZH^{-1} = HZH$